# Is it possible to remove Debian 8 GRUB background from Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, grub2, mate, ubuntu-mate

I have two laptops upgraded to Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS.

The first laptop was upgraded Ubuntu 10.04 LTS → 12.04 LTS → 14.04 LTS MATE → 16.04 LTS MATE and then to Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS. For some reason this laptop shows wrong GRUB background image (`/usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png` → `/etc/alternatives/desktop-grub` → `/usr/share/images/desktop-base/lines-grub-1920x1080.png`):

> [image: Debian 8 GRUB background]

On second laptop where initially Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS were installed the GRUB background is correct.

What should I change on first laptop to get Ubuntu MATE GRUB background screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first you have to compare lists of installed packages and install the `grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate` package.

Then you have to compare contents of generated `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` files.

To get final solution you have to remove `/usr/share/desktop-base/grub_background.sh` which is called by `/etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme` and should not be there for Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS.

As the result you will get:

[image: correct GRUB background for Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS]